# Gets the number of duplicates in the list - wrong output

Tags: java, arraylist, count, duplicates

How to count duplicates in `ArrayList` and count only once.

Here is what I have so far:

```
  /**
   * Gets the number of duplicates in the list.       
   * Get the next word. It is at index i. Does it match any of the words with index > i?)
   * @return the number of duplicate words in the list
   */
  public int countDuplicates() {
      int duplicates = 0;         
      for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
          for (int j = i; j < list.size(); j++) {
              if (list.get(i).equals(j)) duplicates++;
          }
      }

      return duplicates;
  }
```

Here is check output:

```
Actual: 0
Expected: 3
```

I am missing something very easy. However, couldn't find what exactly it is.

***How to solve this trouble?***

Comment: What are the elements of that list?

Comment: Do you have access to a debugger?

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: Create a new list and add each found duplicate to it. Then test if the new duplicate exists in this list. If it doesn't, add one to the counter.

Comment: list.get(i).equals(j) compares the ith element to the integer j. Try: list.get(i).equals(list.get(j)). Additionally, your second loop should be indexed at (int j = i+1). Otherwise, you're comparing the ith element to the ith element on each repetition of the second loop.

Comment: `if (list.get(i).equals(list.get(j))){ duplicates++;}` should do the trick for you. Right now you compare the lists content at i with the number of j. Plus your second loop starts comparing from the beginning so you end up counting duplicates twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get the jth element you just compare to `j` directly. And as a commenter points out, `j` should start at `i+1` to avoid comparing an element to itself. Therefore, you need to write

```
public int countDuplicates()
  {
      int duplicates = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
          for (int j = i+1; j < list.size(); j++) {
              if (list.get(i).equals(list.get(j))) duplicates++;
          }
      }

      return duplicates;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
public int countDuplicates()
{
  int duplicates = 0;
  // TODO: Write the code to get the number of duplicates in the list
  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
          if (list.get(i).equals(list.get(j))) duplicates++;
      }
  }

  return duplicates;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two sets for this:

```
final Set<X> set = new HashSet<>();
final Set<X> dups = new HashSet<>();

int dupCount = 0;

for (final X x: list) {
    if (set.add(x)) // first time the element is seen
        continue;
    // Dup; see whether it is the first time we see it
    if (dups.add(x))
        dupCount++;
}

return dupCount;
```

This relies on the fact that `Set`'s `.add()` returns true if and only if the set has been modified as the result of the operation. And note that it traverses the list only once.

Comment: I'd use a `Map` instead of `Set` and/or `List`.

Comment: Hmmyes, that's true, with a map it can be even shorter. But you'd have to take care of not double counting duplicates too.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing index `j` value instead of value of list `list.get(j)`.

Do

```
if (list.get(i).equals(list.get(j)))
```

instead of
    `if (list.get(i).equals(j`))

Comment: The problem with the set solution you propose is that it counts all duplicates: `[1, 1, 1]` will return `2` but OP wants `1`

Comment: @fge yes, it was mistake. so finally he must write loop and compare with each element. because AFAIK there is no any method in `collection` which return `List` with same type object.

Answer (score 1):

I can see three problems with your current code:

1. You are not comparing pairs of elements.  You are actually comparing an element with an index.
2. Your inner loop is comparing element i and element i ... and that would result in a false "duplicate" count.
3. If you have *more than* 2 copies of any given element, then you will get too many duplicate counts.  (To see why, try to "hand execute" with a list of (say) three identical elements.

In fact, you have to EITHER use an auxiliary data structure (e.g. 2 Sets or a Map) OR modify the input list to avoid counting duplicates more than once.

---

I would note that your statement of the problem is ambiguous.  "... only count each duplicate once" could mean that '[1, 1, 1]' gives either 1 or 2.  It depends whether you consider each individual `1` to be a duplicate to be counted once or that we have `1` as one of a set of duplicates ... that must only be counted once.